# CSS hover not working after initial animation

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, keyframe

I have a basic button, which I animate initially. But once animated, I want to add a new animation on hover; but it seems to not work for some reason.

For example:

**button animation:**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #feffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 #686f7638;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  animation: testing 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

@keyframes testing {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-btn">></div>
</div>
```

My guess is that for the CSS animation I'm using `forwards`, but I really need `forwards` to be there.

Comment: If I understand properly: the button keeps moving to the right and when hovered, it scales by 1.5. In your ideal world: do you want to the button keeps moving while hovered (which ultimately makes it unhovered if you don't follow it)? Does the animations keeps going after the hover (with a scale=1 as not hovered)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because the `forwards` that make the animation to override the transform. Instead of `forwards` you can do like below:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #feffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 #686f7638;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  transition:0.5s;
  animation: testing 1s ease-in;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  transform: translateX(100px) scale(1.5);
}

@keyframes testing {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-btn">></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having the initial transform value set. Which is why I needed the forwards. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Doodoo you want to have a transition on hover or not? if you don't need transition I have another way with forwards

Comment: Yes I need transition on hover, and initial animation with forwards

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

how about adding  'animation-fill-mode: none' to '.slide-btn:hover':

```
.slide-btn:hover {
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```